# Ecuacion primer grado R

Tags: r, rstudio

Quiero Crear una función que me resuelva una ecuación de primer grado (de la forma Ax+B=0). Es decir, vosotros tendréis que introducir como parámetros los coeficientes (en orden) y la función tiene que devolver la solución. Por ejemplo, si la ecuación es 2x+4=0, vuestra función os tendría que devolver -2.

```
fun=function(a,b){
    ax+b=0
}
fun(2,3)
```

Esta solucion para crear el script me arrojz error... cual es la sintaxis correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `R` base la función `solve` permite obtener la inversa de una matriz cuadrada `(filas = columnas)` la cual usa la forma `Ax=b`. Con ello se puede resolver [sistemas de ecuaciones lineales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_ecuaciones_lineales) mediante la inversa de `A`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La implementación de las funciones en `R` así como la asignación de valores en las variables requieren del operador `<-` en lugar del `=`

### Opción 1:

```
linear_solver_1 <- function(A,b){
  # Ax + b = 0
  solve(A) %*% (-b) # solve(A): la inversa de la matriz cuadrada A
}

linear_solver_2 <- function(A,b){
  # Ax = b
  solve(A) %*% (b)  # solve(A): la inversa de la matriz cuadrada A
}
```

Su empleo:

```
# 2x + 3 = 0
print(linear_solver_1(2,3)) # Rpta: -1.5


# 2x = -3
print(linear_solver_3(2,-3)) # Rpta: -1.5

# x + y - 4 = 0
# x - y - 2 = 0
a <- rbind(c(1,1), c(1,-1))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1   -1
b <- c(-4,-2)
print(linear_solver_1(a,b)) # Rpta: 3, 1 (x, y)


# x + y = 4
# x - y = 2
a <- rbind(c(1,1), c(1,-1))
b <- c(4,2)
print(linear_solver_2(a,b)) # Rpta: 3, 1 (x, y)
```

### Opción 2:

También si se tiene que `a %*% x = b` basta con hacer lo siguiente `solve(a, b)`

```
linear_solver_1 <- function(A,b){
  # Ax + b = 0
  solve(A, -b)
}

linear_solver_2 <- function(A,b){
  # Ax = b
  solve(A, b)
}
```

### Qué es %*%

Este es el operador de multiplicación para matrices que emplea `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Debes resolver la ecuación Ax+B=0,  x = -b/a entonces es: 
`fun <- function(a, b) -b/a`

Comment: Esto no te funcionaria si es que fuera así: ax + b = y;  lo contrario de tu solución que si encajaría si igualas la ecuación a 0.

Comment: Obviamente. Solo respondí la ecuación de la pregunta y la función ejemplo del código que has dado, que es de la forma Ax+B=0. En ningún lugar se indica que A y B son vectores o matrices o que es un sistema lineal.